# Pdist between 2 binary matrices

Tags: image, matlab, hamming-distance

how can I calculate the hamming distance between two binary matrices?

for example:

```
A = [ 1 0 1; 1 1 1 ];
B = [ 1 0 0 ; 0 0 1 ];
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by Hamming distance you mean an element-wise distance between two matrices you can simply use `xor`:

```
D = xor(A,B);
```

And the total distance over elements:

```
D_total = nnz(D);
```